# divs changing place when the window is resized / can't use horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, html, scrollbar, overflow

I'm having a problem with my layout. I have a full width navbar with some divs on it, but when the page is resized the divs inside this navbar change their positions, and I only get a scrollbar at the bottom of the page, probably because of the footer. 
The only percentage I'm keeping on the layout is the navbar one, 100%, since I don't know how to make it full page size without using percentages. I also tried using `overflow: auto;` in both `body` and `container`, none of them seemed to work. 
Here is the fiddle link for the page: http://jsfiddle.net/Drp55/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `min-width: 1300px;` on the body.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Drp55/5/)

Comment: That seemed to work, wouldn't it look weird on monitors bigger than 1300px, though? My monitor is 1336x768 and I get a [bit of the navbar cutted on the right](http://puu.sh/2Bvdn)

Comment: Then set a `max-width`, or just set the `width` of body.

Comment: Nevermind, that problem was because of the `margin: 0em -0.5em 0em -0.5em;`. I still keep my question, though.